# K & R- ex 5.13: writing my own basic version of the UNIX command- tail; Unexpected output due to removal of a comment

Tags: c, unix

The question asks to

> Write a program tail that prints the last n lines of its input. By default, n is 10, let us say, but it can be changed by an optional arguement, so that
>
> tail -n
>
> prints the last n lines

Now, my program takes an optional arguement n at the command line, asks for a filename for input when it executes and prints its last n lines. It also prints some numbers at the beginning that specify the corresponding line's index in the array.

Here's the bug:

When I run this program with 12 as the command line arguement and enter this source file as the filename, it prints infinitely. Here is the code:

```
/*PROGRAM TO PRINT THE LAST 'n' LINES OF INPUT
 *CHECKLILST:
 *  -stores the lines as an array of pointers
 *  -accepts n from the command line
 */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100    /*maximum no. of characters in each line*/
#define DMAX 5      /*default value of no. lines to print*/

void readlines(int *, int *, char **);
void printlines(int *, int *, char **);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int start= 0; /*stores the location of the oldest line read*/
    int n= (argc==1)?DMAX:atoi(argv[1]+1);
            printf("Value of n is %d\n\n", n);
    char *line[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        line[i]= NULL;
    readlines(&start, &n, line);
    printlines(&start, &n, line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*readlines(): reads lines from a file and stores it as required*/
void readlines(int *start, int *n, char *line[])
{
    char cline[SIZE];
    printf("Enter the name of the file\n");
    char filename[20];
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *fin= fopen(filename, "r");

    int i= 0;
    while(fgets(cline, SIZE, fin)) {
        if(line[i%*n]!=NULL)
            free(line[i%*n]);
        line[i%*n]= strdup(cline);

        ++i;

        if(*start+1==*n) {
            *start= 0;
            continue;
        }
        if(i>=*n)
            ++*start;
    }
    --*start;   /*compensate for the extra updation*/
    fclose(fin);
}

/*printlines(): prints the lines*/
void printlines(int *start, int *n, char *line[])
{
    int i=*start;
    do {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, line[i]);
        if(i==*n-1)
            i= 0;
        else
            ++i;
    }
    while(i!=*start && line[i]!=NULL);
}
```

Note- this program works completely fine for all other inputs and arguements. What's even more strange is that when i enter a comment (any comment), or even insert a blank line before the do statement ends,

```
do {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, line[i]);
        if(i==*n-1)
            i= 0;
        else
            ++i;
    }
```

it gives the expected output.

Note2- Most probably you won't get the same error if you modify the sorce as even adding one blank line makes it work fine.

Comment: Note that the *standard* `tail` command does not prompt for a file name.  It reads from its standard input, or from the file(s) named as command-line arguments if there are any.

Comment: You don't check for errors. Add this and run the program in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 71 lines in your file. Which means that for `n == 12` your `readlines` function will finish looping just after setting `*start` to 0.

But then you do this:

```
 --*start;   /*compensate for the extra updation*/
```

You really should make sure that "updation" happened to begin with. Because if it didn't, you end up with `*start == -1`. Your loop then proceeds to run indefinitely, because `i` never equals -1.

A quick fix:

```
if (*start)
  --*start;
else
  *start = *n-1;
```